# AutoFocus in iPhone 4S front camera:- adjustingFocus observer not being invoked

Tags: iphone, ios

For the Key `**adjustingFocus**`
 observer notifies me when i am using the back camera

and does not do anything if using the front camera.

Any ideas on why this is happening ?

*I am testing this on iPhone 4S, iOS 7 latest beta ,using GPUImage*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The front facing camera on the iPhone 4S is a fixed focus camera, so the adjustingFocus observer will never notify you.

You can demonstrate this for yourself by opening the camera app to the front facing camera and checking out a couple things. Try putting a finger close to the camera and noticing that it won't try to pull focus on it. You can also tap around the screen and see the exposure and white balance adjust, but the focus never changing.